# Counting the number of of incidences of a certain number, adding results to a new column

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(SERIAL = c(118694001L, 118694001L, 118694001L, 
118695001L, 118696001L, 118696001L, 118696001L, 118697001L, 118698001L, 
118698001L, 118699001L, 118699001L, 118699001L, 118700001L, 118700001L, 
118701001L, 118701001L), RELATED = c(9999L, 9999L, 9999L, 3100L, 
3100L, 3100L, 3100L, 3100L, 3100L, 3100L, 9999L, 9999L, 9999L, 
3100L, 3100L, 3100L, 3100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

I want to create a new column, 'count,' that counts the incidence of the number 3100 in the column `RELATED`, but it has to be grouped by `SERIAL`.

I have tried

```
df <- within(data, DILs2 <- ave(SERIAL, list(SERIAL, RELATED == 3100), FUN=length))
```

The result should look like this:

```
SERIAL  RELATED Count
118694001   9999    0
118694001   9999    0
118694001   9999    0
118695001   3100    1
118696001   3100    3
118696001   3100    3
118696001   3100    3
118697001   3100    1
118698001   3100    2
118698001   3100    2
118699001   9999    0
118699001   9999    0
118699001   9999    0
118700001   3100    2
118700001   3100    2
118701001   3100    2
118701001   3100    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[,count:=.N,by=c("SERIAL")]
dt[,count:=ifelse(RELATED!=3100,0,count)]

> dt
       SERIAL RELATED count
 1: 118694001    9999     0
 2: 118694001    9999     0
 3: 118694001    9999     0
 4: 118695001    3100     1
 5: 118696001    3100     3
 6: 118696001    3100     3
 7: 118696001    3100     3
 8: 118697001    3100     1
 9: 118698001    3100     2
10: 118698001    3100     2
11: 118699001    9999     0
12: 118699001    9999     0
13: 118699001    9999     0
14: 118700001    3100     2
15: 118700001    3100     2
16: 118701001    3100     2
17: 118701001    3100     2
```

Comment: Error in `:=`(count, .N) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: Yes I did! Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: what is your data frame name?

Comment: I feel you are not using correct `data frame` name.

Comment: it's 'data1990'

Comment: Now I'm getting

Comment: did u  use `data.table::setDT(data1990)` ?

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(count, .N), by = c("SERIAL")) : 
  Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)

Comment: The solution works fine with the sample input provided. Please provide proper input for solution.

Comment: It does work with the input I provided. I think I figured out what the problem was. Thank you!

Comment: No worries! I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for multiple values in RELATED, then using `group_by(SERIAL, RELATED)` and then `mutate(count = n())` will be better.
Below codes might help you going ahead

You could do that using `dplyr` as below:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(SERIAL) %>%
  summarise(count  = sum(RELATED == 3100))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
     SERIAL count
      <int> <int>
1 118694001     0
2 118695001     1
3 118696001     3
4 118697001     1
5 118698001     2
6 118699001     0
7 118700001     2
8 118701001     2
```

Or in `data.table` as:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(count = sum(RELATED == 3100)), SERIAL]
      SERIAL count
1: 118694001     0
2: 118695001     1
3: 118696001     3
4: 118697001     1
5: 118698001     2
6: 118699001     0
7: 118700001     2
8: 118701001     2
```

Or in base R using `aggregate` as:

```
aggregate(RELATED ~ SERIAL, data=df, function(x) {sum(x == 3100)})
     SERIAL RELATED
1 118694001       0
2 118695001       1
3 118696001       3
4 118697001       1
5 118698001       2
6 118699001       0
7 118700001       2
8 118701001       2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your data frame. This can be done with one line of code.

```
 > data.frame(table(df$SERIAL,df$RELATED))
        Var1 Var2 Freq
1  118694001 3100    0
2  118695001 3100    1
3  118696001 3100    3
4  118697001 3100    1
5  118698001 3100    2
6  118699001 3100    0
7  118700001 3100    2
8  118701001 3100    2
9  118694001 9999    3
10 118695001 9999    0
11 118696001 9999    0
12 118697001 9999    0
13 118698001 9999    0
14 118699001 9999    3
15 118700001 9999    0
16 118701001 9999    0
```

The rest is aesthetics.

Hope this is helpful.